# rotation of a plane in horizontally

Tags: c++, rotation

i am having a very simple question, but this confused me how to do this in c++.

Here, I have an oblique plane who normal vector is (a,b,c). Now I want to rotate this plane horizontally by 90 and 180 degrees. i.e. i want to rotate plane normal in XY plane by 90 and 180 degrees.

the problem is i do not know in which quadrant that vector falls. it may be in first or third...or any other.

So, my question is, any general formula to get rotated vectors by 90 and 180 degrees.

for example, if the updated vector is [a1,b1,c] (by 90) and [a2,b2,c] (by 180), what would be a1,b1 and a2, b2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a1 = -b
b1 =  a

a2 = -a
b2 = -b
```

Answer (score 1):

A little more general: rotating [x,y,z] an angle theta around the Z-axis becomes

```
[x,y,z]->[cos(theta)*x-sin(theta)*y , sin(theta)*x+cos(theta)*y , z]
```